# The last record in the array returns null

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a PHP exercise script for the elevator and the people there, it's not important, because everything is ready, though - there was a problem at the end of the task. I want to display the last record of an array, more specifically the weight.

Sorry, I'm getting a null argument error, although print_r of the last array record returns the correct data. What am I doing wrong?

```
$elevatorContent = array (

    array (
    "firstname" => "Peter",
    "weight" => 70
    ),

    array (
    "firstname" => "Cassie",
    "weight" => 70
    ),

    array (
    "firstname" => "John",
    "weight" => 150
    ),

    array (
    "firstname" => "Agnes",
    "weight" => 150
    ),

);
```

This returns null

```
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>".end($elevatorContent['firstname']). "<b></p>";
```

Comment: you can quick-fix with: echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>". end(end($elevatorContent)). "<b></p>";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need small correction :

php [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) returns last element of given array, so you have to get last element first, and then access it by your key.

Since PHP 5.4 :

From

```
end($elevatorContent['firstname'])
```

To

```
echo end($elevatorContent)["firstname"];
```

**OR**

On PHP 5.3 or earlier, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

```
$last_arr = end($elevatorContent);
echo $last_arr["firstname"];
```

So it becomes:

```
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>" . end($elevatorContent)['firstname'] . "<b></p>";
```

OR

```
$last_arr = end($elevatorContent);
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>".$last_arr["firstname"]. "<b></p>";
```

Comment: You were right, it works - thanks ;) I mark your answer as problem solved, but i need wait 8 mins ;)

Comment: $last = end($elevatorContent);
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>".$last['firstname']. "<b></p>";

Comment: end(); return only array format so you can not return direct array

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>" . end($elevatorContent)['firstname'] . "<b></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>" . $elevatorContent[count($elevatorContent) - 1]['firstname'] . "<b></p>";
```

Comment: While not wrong, it is now hardcoded. What if the list of names is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
$last = end($elevatorContent);
echo "<p>The last person in elevator is <b>".$last['firstname']. "<b></p>";
```